# Problem with using a IF condition on Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

Fisrt i want to say that i'm not a programer and i just see codes inside of GTM so sorry if something is wrong

I need to pull an ID from my websites datalayer for a TAG on GTM. But when the visitor isn't logged on it comes as "undefined" and i need it to be empty so i used a IF condition for this

```
     "uuid":if({{user_id}} == undefined) {
        "" "";
      } else {
  {{user_id}};
  }
```

Am i missing something about the syntaxe, because it keeps coming with errors

thanks

i tried putting a function as

```
     "uuid":function() {
if({{user_id}} == undefined) {
        "" "";
      } else {
  {{user_id}};
  }
}
```

But i dont even know if this make sense

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing doesn't make much sense, but I think this is enough to see what you're trying to achieve.

Make a Custom JavaScript variable with the following content:

```
function(){
  return {{user_id}} || "";
}
```

Then reference this CJS variable in your dimension setting.

See if it fits your needs. I skipped the stringy "undefined" check, but will add it if this still doesn't work.